# Deallocation error of Matplotlib embeded in Pyside 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyside2

I am executing [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt5.html) example file for matplotlib and I am getting the following error while exiting the mainwindow normally.

```
Fatal Python error: deallocating None
```

I have only changed the following lines, because i wanted to use PySide2 instead of PyQt.

Original:

```
# Make sure that we are using QT5
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
```

New:

```
# Make sure that we are using QT5
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt5']='PySide2'
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
```

The program otherwise runs perfectly, it just crashes when i close it, which is a bit irritating.

My environment consists of:

- Python 3.6.4
- PySide2 5.6.0a1
- MatplotLib 2.2.2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/49712824/6704496, it appears a not up-to-date version bug. Please download the newest wheel http://download.qt.io/snapshots/ci/pyside/5.9/latest/.